# Why does comparing strings in Ruby always return false?

Tags: ruby

I use the following to check whether the answer to a posed question is true or false:

```
when "new" 
  n = nums[rand(nums.length)]
  puts "Question:"
  puts qs[n].question
  torf = gets.downcase.to_str.eql? qs[n].answer.downcase.to_str
  puts torf
```

But the result `torf` is always false even if the right answer is put. What am I missing?

Comment: Bad question. You have many variables/methods without explanation (nums, qs, question, answer). You also are not closing `when` with `end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets` will return the entered string plus a newline charcter, so you'll need to remove it. As it is a string you don't need to run to_str on the result either.

```
 torf = gets.downcase.chomp.eql? qs[n].answer.downcase.to_s
```

Comment: You can also rewrite `n = nums[rand(nums.length)]` to be: `n = nums.sample`

Comment: You should be using `to_s`, not `to_str`.

Comment: Adding to @Phrogz 's comment, here is an [article on `to_s` vs `to_str`](http://briancarper.net/blog/98/)